# How to use await for making my controller's method asynchronous?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I want to make my controller and its methods asynchronous, but I don't know where to put "await".

In my controller's method, I called a method of service layer that gets data from a database by using a linq query:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

    public MyController()
    {
         this.service = new MyService(db);
    }

    public List<dynamic> myMethod(FormCollection post)
    {
        var x = post["itemOne"];
        List<dynamic> myVar = service.getFromdb(x);
        return var;
    }
}
```

The Linq query takes a lot of time, and I want to put `await` at the beginning of this line.

My Linq query is something like this:

```
public MyService : IMyService 
{
    public List<dynamic> getFromdb(string x)
    {
        var query = (from dum in db.TableOne 
                     where dum.colOne == x
                     select new
                            {
                                col1 = dum.colOne,
                                col2 = dum.colTwo,
                                col3 = dum.colThree,
                            })
                   .Union(from dum2 in db.TableOne 
                          where dum.colTwo == x
                          select new
                                 {
                                     col1 = dum2.colOne,
                                     col2 = dum2.colTwo,
                                     col3 = dum2.colThree,
                                 })
                   .GroupBy(g => new 
                                 {
                                     myG1 = g.colOne,
                                     myG2 = g.colTwo,
                                 })
                   .Select(s => new 
                                {
                                    col1 = s.Key.myG1,
                                    col2 = s.Key.myG2,
                                    col3 = s.Count()
                                })
                   .Join(db.TableTwo,
                         g => new { g.col1, g.col2 },
                         t => new { t.col1, t.col2 },
                         (g,t) => new 
                                  {
                                      finalCol1 = g.col1,
                                      finalCol2 = g.col2,
                                      finalCol3 = g.col3,
                                      finalCol4 = t.colX,
                                      finalCol5 = t.colY,
                                  })
                  .OrderByDescenging(y => new { mycol1 = y.finalCol1 , mycol2 = y.finalCol2 })
                  .Select(s => s);

        if (SOMETHING TRUE)
        {
            return query.Skip(1000)
                        .Take(500)
                        .Select(s => s)
                        .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
             return query.Skip(2000)
                         .Take(100)
                         .Select(s => s)
                        .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change my method `myMethod` to this:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public async List<dynamic> myMethod(FormCollection post)
    {
        var x = post["itemOne"];
        List<dynamic> myVar = await service.getFromdb(x);
        return var;
    }
}
```

but in service I tried to change `query` and use await:

```
public async List<dynamic> getFromdb(string x)
{
      var query = await (from dum in db.TableOne 
        .......
}
```

but I don't know how to change the Linq query to asynchronous.

I want to add async to my method but I got confused what to do

Comment: You can't use `await` to magically make a synchronous method asynchronous. You use it to await an already asynchronous method. Instead of using `var results=query.ToList()` use `var results=await query.ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Additionally, you should not be using `dynamic` here at all. It won't help you, it will only cause problems.

Comment: `new MyEntities();` <-- If you're doing this, it means you've got a connection-string hardcoded in your program code, which means your code won't work when run on a different computer or environment. Please learn how to use DI properly.

Comment: What are you expecting async code to actually accomplish for you here? How will this be better with async controller methods?

Comment: Also, just introducing  `async / await` isn't going to magically make this code run faster ....

Comment: @Dai There's probably a config file.

Comment: Where's `Task<>`?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous methods won't make your queries faster or the methods calling the queries faster. In fact, it will make the methods calling the queries slightly slower. What it will do is allow something like a web server to be more responsive in that it will hand off the web request to a background worker and resume responding to other user requests. (That awaited original request will still be waiting for a response as long as this query takes, until it times out)

So with that in mind the missing bit is that asynchronous methods return Tasks:

```
public async Task<List<dynamic>> myMethodAsync(FormCollection post)
{
    var x = post["itemOne"];
    List<dynamic> myVar = await service.getFromdb(x);
    return var;
}
```

and

```
public async Task<List<dynamic>> getFromDbAsync(string x, int page, int pageSize)
{
    var query = ... 

    return await query.Skip(page*pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize)
                    .ToListAsync();
}
```

For methods (other than things like controller actions) you should suffix asynchronous declarations with "Async" especially if you have a mix of asynchronous and synchronous variations. If you were to call `getFromDbAsync()` without an `await` you would be returned the `Task` which itself could be awaited or Waited on with a WaitAll etc. Note that EF's DbContext is not thread safe so do not attempt to parallelize queries like this if using a common injected `DbContext` instance. When you add `await`, the task will automatically given a resumption point and the code after the awaited call will be dealing with the returned data type. I.e. `List<dynamic>`.

```
var results = getFromDbAsync(someValue, 0, 500); // results = Task<List<dynamic>>

var results = await getFromDbAsync(someValue, 0, 500); // results = List<dynamic>
```

As for improving performance? Some simple tips. Don't try to be clever or lazy with your coding. `dynamic` is a huge red flag for something like this. Use concrete DTOs to project to for each of the specific scenarios. Also when it comes to read operations from input from users, base this on only what they actually need, not what you think they might want, or even what they say they want. Giving users overly flexible querying capabilities is a sure way to sink a project. It's giving them a claymore mine with no instruction manual instead of a mouse trap when they tell you they have a mouse problem. If 95% of the time simpler, indexed queries with a reasonable number of parameters can get the job done, then build and index for those. Building complex, dynamic results and criteria will lead to slower, buggier code, and situations where that remaining 5% you are chasing to satisfy result in queries that literally bring your system down to a crawl. Non-indexed, expensive queries touching too many tables, creating row locks slowing everything else down.. Then users find it takes too long so they close the tab and open a new one, or figure they'll kick several off in the background.